# Check if text in UILabel is equal to string iOS Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I have a UILabel where I am saying whether is is an "A Day, B Day, etc." Our school goes on an A-G day rotation so this is telling users what day today is. (The days are pulled from a large NSDictionary that matches up letter days with real dates)

I want to display a different image depending on what day it is. so something like

```
// (in pseudo-code) 

if [UILabel == @"A Day"]{ 
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Aday.jpg"];
}
```

I am putting `A Day` into my label like this: `[dictionary setObject:@"A Day" forKey:@"2012-05-15"];` then doing `[letterday setText:[dictionary objectForKey:LetterDay]];`.

Is there a way to use this same dictionary and do what I am trying above?

What would be the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

edit: this is what I have...still not working. Any tips?

```
NSMutableDictionary *imageforlabel = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


                [imageforlabel setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ADay.png"] forKey:@"A Day"];
                [imageforlabel setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BDay.png"] forKey:@"B Day"];
                [imageforlabel setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CDay.png"] forKey:@"C Day"];
                [imageforlabel setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DDay.png"] forKey:@"D Day"];
                [imageforlabel setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EDay.png"] forKey:@"E Day"];
                [imageforlabel setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FDay.png"] forKey:@"F Day"];
                [imageforlabel setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GDay.png"] forKey:@"G Day"];

rotationday.image = [imageforlabel objectForKey:letterday.TEXT];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define an ivar `NSDictionary *imageForLabel`, and set it up as follows in your designated initializer:

```
imageForLabel = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"Aday.jpg"], @"A Day"
,   [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bday.jpg"], @"B Day"
,   [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cday.jpg"], @"C Day"
,   // ...and so on
,   nil];
```

Then at runtime look up the imgage from the `NSDictionary`:

```
UIImage *image = [imageForLabel objectForKey:label.text];
```

Comment: hey...tried to implement this but still not working...I updated my question with the code... if you have time could you check it out and see if anything looks wrong? thanks!

Comment: @Fitz This is because you are storing `NSString*` objects representing names of your images, rather than images themselves in the dictionary. It should be `[dictionary setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ADay.png"] forKey:@"A Day"];`

Comment: could the problem be that I am using a nsmutable dictionary? I tried what you said above but still not working...I updated the new code in my original question if you want to check it out... thanks!

Comment: ah, got it. at runtime I needed to add .text after the label. Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 5):

The code you are looking for is this:

```
if ([myLabel.text isEqualToString:@"A Day"]) {
```

But this is a **terrible** way to write your program.  Somewhere, you decided to put the string `@"A Day"` in your label.  **That** is where you should also decide what image to display.

#### Edit

In response to your comment: one easy approach would be to have a dictionary that maps each date string to the appropriate image.  Example:

```
[labelMap setObject:@"A Day" forKey:dateString];
[imageMap setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Aday.jpg"] forKey:dateString];

...

letterDayLabel.text = [labelMap objectForKey:letterDay];
letterDayImage.image = [imageMap objectForKey:letterDay];
```

A somewhat more complex approach, and what I'd probably use in my own implementation, is to create a `RotationDay` class that represents a particular day in the rotation, and holds the “assets” for each day: the day's label and image.  In the future if you add more assets (multiple images for a single day, or a short label and a long label, or animations, or sounds), you add them to the  class.  Example:

```
@interface RotationDay : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *labelText;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) UIImage *image;

+ (RotationDay *)dayForLetter:(NSString *)letter;
@end

@implementation RotationDay
@synthesize labelText = _labelText;
@synthesize image = _image;

static NSMutableDictionary *daysMap() {
    static NSMutableDictionary *theMap;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{ theMap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; });
    return theMap;
}

+ (RotationDay *)uncachedDayForLetter:(NSString *)letter {
    RotationDay *day = [[RotationDay alloc] init];
    day->_labelText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ Day", letter];
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@day.jpg", letter];
    day->_image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    return day;
}

+ (RotationDay *)dayForLetter:(NSString *)letter {
    NSMutableDictionary *map = daysMap();
    RotationDay *day = [map objectForKey:letter];
    if (!day) {
        day = [self uncachedDayForLetter:letter];
        [map setObject:day forKey:letter];
    }
    return day;
}

@end
```

Then, you would use it like this:

```
[dictionary setObject:[RotationDay dayForLetter:@"A"] forKey:@"2012-05-15"];

...

RotationDay *day = [dictionary objectForKey:LetterDay];
letterday.text = day.labelText;
imageday.image = day.image;
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that it is really a __terrible__ way of doing it.

Comment: ok thanks...I am putting A Day into my label like this:  
    `[dictionary setObject:@"A Day" forKey:@"2012-05-15"];` then doing  `[letterday setText:[dictionary objectForKey:LetterDay]];`        is there a way to use this same dictionary and do what I am trying above? Thanks for pointing out I wasn't doing it the right way!

Answer (score 3):

```
UILabel *label;

if ([label.text isEqualToString:@"A Day"]) {

}
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([Your_LAbel.text isEqualtoString : @"A Day"])
{
//Your code;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quiet simple to do:

Here is the code:

```
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[label text]]]];
```

In your question label = @"A Day" and image = "Aday.jpg". So I have preferred this one.

```
image = [image stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]; 
NSString *finalImageName = [image stringByAppendingString:@"jpg"];
UIImage img = [UIImage imageNamed:finalImageName];
```

Hope this will work for you

Enjoy coding :)

Comment: Use your image name same as your label text.

Comment: This only works if the images have the same name as the labels. But in OP example, there is an extra space. But your solution is great if they they do have the same name as the labels.

Comment: Check my updated ans to remove unwanted space. And obviously there should be some sync between imagename and label text